# Mapping Exception error with Doctrine in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

i need your help because it's like a day i'm stuck with a mapping problem in Symfony 2.

First of all, i'm new to Symfony, i have only 2 weeks of practice with that framework.
So let's talk about my real problem. The synopsis is simple, i have a very simple form that i use to create a categorie (CD/DVD/Books, etc..). So normally,my page displays all categorie that already exists and i input a new categorie (like BLU-RAY for ie), then that categorie is saved on my database named Categorie with these attributes (idcategorie=BLU-RAY, idcatalogue=CAT01).

That's the normal situation, in my case, i can list list all my categorie but when i submit my form, i've got a beautiful

> The class 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository' was not found in the chain
>   configured namespaces SEBO\BackOfficeBundle\Entity

First this my controller

```
public function categorieAction(Request $request)
{
    $categorie = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SEBOBackOfficeBundle:Categorie');
    $listeCategorie = $categorie->findAll();

    $newCategorie = new Categorie();
    $newCategorie->setIdcatalogue('CAT01');

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($newCategorie)
        ->add('idcategorie', 'text')
        ->add('Ajouter', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($categorie);
        $em->flush();

        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Catégorie bien enregistrée.');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sebo_back_office_categorie', array(
            'listeCategorie' => $listeCategorie,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        )));
    }

    $content = $this->get('templating')->render('SEBOBackOfficeBundle:Advert:categorie.html.twig', array(
        'listeCategorie' => $listeCategorie,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
    return new Response($content);
}
```

This is my class Categorie.php

```
namespace SEBO\BackOfficeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Categorie
*
* @ORM\Table(name="categorie", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="FK_Catalogue_IdCatalogue", columns={"IdCatalogue"})})
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Categorie
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="IdCategorie", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $idcategorie;

/**
 * @var \Catalogue
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Catalogue")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="IdCatalogue", referencedColumnName="IdCatalogue")
 * })
 */
private $idcatalogue;



/**
 * Get idcategorie
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getIdcategorie()
{
    return $this->idcategorie;
}

/**
 * Set idcatalogue
 *
 * @param string $idcatalogue
 * @return Categorie
 */
public function setIdcatalogue($idcatalogue)
{
    $this->idcatalogue = $idcatalogue;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set idcategorie
 *
 * @param string $idcategorie
 * @return Categorie
 */
public function idcategorie($idcategorie)
{
    $this->idcategorie = $idcategorie;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idcatalogue
 *
 * @return \SEBO\BackOfficeBundle\Entity\Catalogue 
 */
public function getIdcatalogue()
{
    return $this->idcatalogue;
}
}
```

and that's my Doctrine/ORM xml file for Categorie.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Categorie" table="categorie">
    <indexes>
      <index name="FK_Catalogue_IdCatalogue" columns="IdCatalogue"/>
    </indexes>
    <id name="idcategorie" type="string" column="IdCategorie" length="40">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
<many-to-one field="idcatalogue" target-entity="Catalogue">
  <join-columns>
    <join-column name="IdCatalogue" referenced-column-name="IdCatalogue"/>
  </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
 </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Everything works fine until i submit, i can see my list of categorie but after a lot of search, i still can't see what's that  class 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository', i've surely missed a thing and i hope you will help.
Thanks for your future answer.

Comment: Did you register `BackOfficeBundle` in your `app/AppKernel.php`?

Comment: Yes i do, otherwise it will impossible for me to reach my url or use my form.

Comment: Looks like some of your entity extending `EntityRepository` class

Comment: No, i've checked all my entities and none of them extending `EntityRepository` class.

Answer (score 0):

In you're entity, you have to set:

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

There is an example on this page:

[Databases and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok maybe because i'm tired but i was trying to send the object $categorie and not the new one i've created $newCategorie